# Jquery refresh page depends on if-else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, refresh

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function applyclass()
{
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();

if (n >= 3 && n < 7) 
$('timeOfDay').addClass('dawn');

else if (n >= 7 && n < 11) 
$('timeOfDay').addClass('morning');

else if (n >= 11 && n < 15)
$('timeOfDay').addClass('day');

else if (n >= 15 && n < 19) 
$('timeOfDay').addClass('sunset');

else if (n >= 19 && n < 21) 
$('timeOfDay').addClass('dusk');

else
$('timeOfDay').addClass('night');

}

window.onload = applyclass;
</script>
```

My code like above. What i want to do is refreshing the page in every condition. If it fits the current case page should get refreshed once for taking effects. Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Why add a class then immediately reload the page?

Comment: Adding a class takes effect immediately, no need for a page refresh?

Comment: why you need that refresh? can you explain a little further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your question. your class is not showing because you don't use $( document ).ready(); try this...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
applyclass();
});
```

instead of

```
window.onload = applyclass;
```

if you add a class it should be visible immediately. No page refresh is needed.

you also need to specify whether your selector is a class or an id. like so (mind the "." which means it is a class)

```
$('.timeOfDay').addClass('sunset');
```

here is a working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/ztTv2/1/

Comment: I've changed the code but now it does not apply classes to my div  <div id="timeOfDay"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Simply add ?

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: if (n >= 3 && n < 7) 
{
$('timeOfDay').addClass('dawn');
window.location.reload();
}

..... doesn't work refreshes every second :(